# I have problem Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem in this case, the problem is 
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

**This is my Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './../../_models/user';
import { UserService } from './../../_services/user.service';
import { AlertifyService } from './../../_services/alertify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-detail',
  templateUrl: './member-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-detail.component.css']
})
export class MemberDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadUser();
  }

  loadUser() {
    this.userService.getUser(+this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((user: User) => {  //error Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      this.user = user;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

}
```

**And**

**This is my _model**

```
import { Photo } from './photo';

export interface User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    knownAs: string;
    age: number;
    gender: string;
    created: Date;
    lastActive: Date;
    photoUrl: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
    interests?: string;
    introduction?: string;
    lookingFor?: string;
    photos?: Photo[];
}
```

I expect the ['id'] can be a number argument

Comment: getUser() expects a string. But you're converting the string parameter to a number using `+`. So, either remove the `+`, or fix the getUser() method to take a number as argument rather than a string.

Comment: what's your response from this.userService.getUser? is the response data contains id with number format?

Comment: Thank for the solution, it's work

Answer (score 0):

getUser() expects a string. But you're converting the string parameter to a number using +. So, either remove the +, or fix the getUser() method to take a number as argument rather than a string. – [JB Nizet][1], *It's Works*

Thanks